# Vertical align top in css

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Here is my code

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:text-top; border:1px solid red;float:right;">
     <span>Key:</span>
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbKey" MaxLength="16" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" imageUrl="_img/btn_submit.gif" Height="22" Width="52" />
</div>
```

I would like all three elements to simply line up at the top. Is this doable?

EDITED:
Source code (rendered) is

```
 <div style="margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:text-top; border:1px solid red;float:right;">
                <span>Key:</span>
                <input name="tbKey" type="text" maxlength="16" id="tbKey" />

                <input type="image" name="btnRefresh" id="btnRefresh" src="_img/btn_submit.gif" style="height:22px;width:52px;border-width:0px;border-width:1px;" />

            </div>
```

Comment: that's your .net code. Show us the rendered HTML/CSS.

Comment: just edited the question, see above

Answer (score 14):

I usually use

```
 display: inline-block;
```

in this situation.  That should cause the layout to respect

```
vertical-align: top;
```

rules.

This is similar to @Jason Ellis's `table-cell` solution, but more semantic since this is not a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `vertical-align: text-top` attribute to your button. In CSS:

```
#btnRefresh
{
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Or add `VerticalAlign="Top"` to your ImageButton control (not sure how this last one translates to CSS).

Comment: doesn't work. Adding vertical-align: text-top; to the button just pushes the other 2 elements up. And when removed, the button is up, so it's the vice versa of one would expect. I am sure that CSS ninjas wil explain why:)

Comment: @gnomixa, sorry I must have misunderstood you. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `vertical-align: top;` (for inline element only) This doesn't work with block level element like div. So, the solution is set a fixed width for div element and `display: inline;` It also needs a height value.

Answer (score 0):

Try styling your css like this:

```
div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```